# Paypal recurring payments with variable amount in Asp dot net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal, payment-gateway

Paypal recurring payments with variable amount in ASP.NET Core MVC I am working on a student online payment using Paypal payment gateway and ASP.NET Core MVC.

I have completed the initial module of paying the amount from student account to administrative account using sandbox environment but facing a problem in proceeding further.

The requirement is to auto debit fee from students account on scheduled duration weekly or monthly while the fee amount will differ from their last paid fee amount, the PayPal developer documentation suggest to use Paypal Subscription or Paypal Recurring Payment, but since the fee will not be same for every payment, I hope subscription won't be best suitable for this also could not able to find sufficient implementation or code samples for this.

My questions:

1. Will Paypal Subscription be right logic this requirement?
2. Is there any other concept in Paypal to achieve this requirement programmatically?
3. Has anyone implemented subscription or created a recurring payment plan using ASP.NET Core MVC?

Please share you knowledge. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

When using PayPal Subscriptions, revising the subscription to a different amount or plan requires the payer's consent. This is not suitable if the amount is going to change every cycle.

An integration that does not require the payer's consent for changing amounts will use a feature called "reference transactions" or sometimes "billing agreements". It is not enabled for PayPal business accounts by default. To request the feature, the owner of the live PayPal account should [contact PayPal's general business support](https://www.paypal.com/smarthelp/contact-us) (note: not technical support) and explain the business need for this reference transactions feature.

If it's approved for the account, PayPal can then guide you on which integration to use -- be it the older billing agreements API or a newer v2 or v3 vault one.